# Do stickerless cubes provide speedsolvers with an advantage?

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles, speedsolving

In July 2015 the World Cube Association changed their regulations to allow the use of stickerless puzzles in speed solving. I'm curious whether or not that event changed the sport somehow. Are some professional solvers still using cubes with stickers or did everyone move to stickerless cubes on day one? Is someone collecting statistics about the use of different cube types?

Comment: Check this link out: https://www.quora.com/Which-speed-cube-is-better-stickered-or-stickerless

Comment: Stickerless used to be disallowed because you can see colours of the rear faces without tilting the cube as much, giving you an advantage. As far as I understand it, it was realised that at the speed of the top solvers this was not really something you could take advantage of.

Comment: Some people find stickerless easier for recognition - others harder. It's personal preference. There are fast solvers that main both kinds of cubes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stickerless cubes used to be banned because for a while mostly because there was the idea that you could cheat if the cube was [partly turned](http://cubercritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/stickered-vs-stickerless-cubes.jpg). If one of the layers is at a 45 degree angle, then you can see both the color of the 'sticker' facing you and the 'sticker' on the other side that you wouldn't normally be able to see. Doing this 45 degree turn on a stickered cube wouldn't give you the 'advantage' because you would just see white/black plastic instead of the two colors of the pieces.

However, almost no one used this 'advantage' because it really wasn't one. People solve way too fast for them to slow down and check the inside colors of the pieces of plastic. Not only that, but it would probably be **slower** to turn a layer and check the color of the other side than it would be to just tilt the cube a little bit and look at the other side. It was decided that the rule was not worth it's effort simply because it was attempting to fix a problem that wasn't really there.

Answer (score 4):

This is what Glenn said on [JRCuber](https://jrcuber.com/forums/topic/stickerless-vs-stickered-and-do-they-feel-different/):

*"I have only one Stickerless 3×3, 6 Stickered.
To me there is a completely different feel you can go way faster if set up properly. As well as you don’t have to worry about nails scratching and stickers grinding. All smooth plastic.*

*Plastic for speed solving.

Stickered for big cubes.

Hope that helps."*